# How can I delete my account?

Tags: support, deleted-users

I inadvertently created an account at this StackExchange site but am not going to be using it, and I like to keep my StackExchange account as clean as possible, so I'd like to delete it.  I have not posted or voted (well, except for this question).  How can I delete my account?

Answer (score 5):

If you have not posted or voted, you should see a "delete" option on your profile page (next to "edit").

Otherwise, you can request deletion of your account by following the instructions [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion).  (Additional info on [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/162102).)